# Combobox coding is not displaying in pagesource

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a collection_select tag as 1st combobox and for 2nd combo i have used basic html syntax, on selecting the value of first combo the second combobobx value is populated. this functioning is working prpoperly but on viewing the page source it is not displaying the populated value under option tag.

My view page is..

```
 <% form_tag (:action =>:verify)do%>
                            <%= label_tag(:user,"Select Student") %><br/>
                            <%= collection_select("std", "id",@result,"sid", "sid",:prompt=>"--Select Student--")%><h9>&nbsp;*</h9><br/>
 <select id = 'sub_id'>
  <option value="1">--Select Server--</option>
 </select>
 <%= submit_tag 'Submit',:id => 'btn'%>
```

On change event of first combo i m calling following jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#std_id").change(function() {
      jQuery.get('/controllers/find_val/?sid=' + jQuery("#edetail_id").val(), function(data) {

         var ds = data.split(' ');
         ds.pop();
         var options;
         jQuery.each(ds, function(index, item) {

               options += "<option value='" + ds[index] + "'>" + ds[index] + "</option>";

        });
        jQuery("#sub_id").empty();
         jQuery("#sub_id").append(options).combobox();

         });
      });
   });
```

My controller is...

```
def find_val
   @res = Student.find(:all, :conditions => ["sid = ?",params[:sid]])
end
```

Everything is going fine, but after appending the value of 2nd combo, the values are not dislaying in page source, hence i m not able to capture selected value of second combo in controller for further processing.

Comment: If you are appending the options dynamically, you probably need a delegated event handler, like the delegated version of on().

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
var options = {};

jQuery.each(ds, function(index, item) {
    options[ds[index]] = ds[item];
});

jQuery("#sub_id").empty();
jQuery("#sub_id").addOption(options, false);
```

Comment: It is not appending the options in second drop down.

Comment: is "sub_id" the second drop down element?

Comment: yes.. this is the code <select id = 'sub_id'>
  <option value="1">--Select Server--</option>
 </select>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21503/discussion-between-sonal-singhal-and-amyth)